# site can't reached when running from docker container

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, docker-for-windows

I am new to Docker community, when I run the sample MVC/API application which I created on .net core 3.1 using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.5.3 on windows 10 pro. I am getting couple of issues:

```
 It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
 The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
 - The following frameworks were found:
3.1.0-preview3.19555.2 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
The specified framework can be found at:
- https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch? 
framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

second, When I run the application on chrome browser I am getting "This site can’t be reached". I did several things to resolve the issue but no luck.

docker ps command will give me the following data:

[image: docker ps]

I am using docker for windows (Docker Desktop ver 2.2.0.5) and my docker file as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1803 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Demo_3_1/Demo_3_1.csproj", "Demo_3_1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Demo_3_1/Demo_3_1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Demo_3_1"
RUN dotnet build "Demo_3_1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Demo_3_1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Demo_3_1.dll"]
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Install latest .net core sdk from here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/sdk-3.1.201-windows-x64-installer

Comment: If you run/debug through visual studio, is the browser connecting on **port 80**? when you connect to your app in the docker container it is on **port 59884**.

Comment: @FrankNielsen - I have installed latest version of VS2019 and install .net core sdk but still the problem exists.

Comment: After installing the new SDK, remember to change "TargetFramework" on you project(s) to the new version. At least you should get rid of `The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.`

Comment: @FrankNielsen- I tried everything, there is some problems with Docker itself, When I run on Linux it works fine but gives error when I switch to windows.

Comment: But are the two images (linux,window) running with the same .net runtime?

Comment: @AnkitGupta I'm having a similar issue, did you find a solution?